# How find deleted or removed file under clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I need to modify a Simulink project stored under clearcase. From this project I must generate the C code, but this not the problem. The problem is that all generated files (*.c and other) are saved into clearcase and the code generation delete some file without overwrite the old version with new. Fortunately seems only for files different from *.C but in any case under clearcase (I use a windows client) I found in correspondence of deleted file:

1. the file name
2. three colored question marks

I think that clearcase has the  information regarding the file stored but is not able to allocate this.
Now I need a command/script for CC which help me to found ALL removed files from the view because the project structure is very complex and a manually search is hard.
Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: "I could found this files with a "find checked out", right?" Do you mean you couldn't? Do you see a checked out version when doing a version tree on one of those files?

Comment: I means that if an object that in clearcase has "three colored question marks" is an object "checked out but removed", then I can write a simple script which explores recursively my project tree and finds the object in checked out state. After I should just after analyzing the result of the script and find what is really in check out and what is in "checked out but removed"

Comment: You could do such a script: all you need to look for is checked out (`cleartool lsco`) files which are not present in the snapshot view on the disk.

Answer (score 1):

"three colored question" marks means "checked out but removed", [as in this example](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21232033) (you can [recover from it by reloading the snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11741114/6309))

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21232033&aid=7]

If an automatic process is generating or deleting files in a snapshot view (it wouldn't be able to do the same in a dynamic view), then you should end up with a bunch of [hijacked files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279352/6309) (as [identified in a snapshot view](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123318)).

You could [check them out and check them in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741062/6309).
For the files that need to be deleted, you can follow "[What's the “proper” way to delete files from a ClearCase snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693274/6309)".

But both process are manual and doesn't scale well.

---

There are two viable options:

1/ Don't version what is generated (you can re-generate it at any time)
2/ If you must version what is generated, then:

- generate it *outside* of the snapshot view
- [use **`clearfsimport`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23815311/6309) to import the result of that generation into the snapshot view: that will checkout the right files *and* will *delete* the files that are no longer generated.
  That would be the right solution for "w I need a command/script for CC which help me to found ALL removed files"